# How to create backup and restore of cassandra using priam tool?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter, priam

I'm trying to create backup and restore for cassandra node using Priam. I want to upload the snapshot into S3 and restore from here.

I found priam setup [Priam setup](https://github.com/Netflix/Priam/wiki/Setup) but I didn't understand the steps given here.

I have created `git clone` and ran

```
./gradlew build
```

I have already setup for ASGs.
Can someone give me fully described steps on how to install and execute backup and restore?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you solved it already. You had to investigate more on how to deploy wars (for example in tomcat server which is basically just moving a war file and starting the server service) and create ASGs (Autoscaling groups) in Amazon webservices (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/GettingStartedTutorial.html).
Basically Priam runs as a webapp in tomcat, is configured in a *.yaml file and helps you manage the cassandra nodes through a REST interface (see: https://github.com/Netflix/Priam/wiki/REST-API)